# Getting values from select and building an image url

Tags: jquery, url, select

I want to get the values out of text input and several select drop-drowns. These will be customer choices.
I then want to pass these values into a URL so as to display an image - ideally as the customer makes their choice, No submit button.
This is what I have so far:

```
 <input type="tex" maxlength="8" value="YOUR REG" id="txt" name=""/>
 <select id="1" name="1" >
    <option value="1">text 1</option>
    <option value="2">text 2</option>
    <option value="3">text 3</option>
    <option value="4">text 4</option>
    <option value="5">text 5</option>
    <option value="6">text 6</option>
</select>
<select id="2" name="2" >
    <option value="1">text 1</option>
    <option value="2">text 2</option>
    <option value="3">text 3</option>
    <option value="4">text 4</option>
    <option value="5">text 5</option>
    <option value="6">text 6</option>
</select>
<select id="3" name="3" >
    <option value="1">text 1</option>
    <option value="2">text 2</option>
    <option value="3">text 3</option>
    <option value="4">text 4</option>
    <option value="5">text 5</option>
    <option value="6">text 6</option>
 </select>
 <div id="pContainer">
    <img id="img" src="http://dir/dir/Default.aspx?1=&2=&3=" class="img-responsive ">
 </div>
 $(document).ready (function DrawImg() {

    var txt = $("#txt").val();
    var 1 = $("#1").val;
    var 2 = $("#2").val;
    var 3 = $("#3").val;


        var url = 'http://dir/dir/Default.aspx?';
        url += 'txt=' + escape(txt);
        url += '&1=' + escape(1);
        url += '&2=' + escape(2);
        url += '&3=' + escape(3);

         $("#pContainer").html("<img src='url'/>");
    }
});
```

As a relative j Query newcomer I just can't seem to get this to work.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting the image URL to be generated every time the user changes the `input` text and `selects` options, so:

```
// Just a shortcut for the document ready
$(function () {
    // On every change to the input or selects
    $("input, select").on("change", function () {
        var txt = $("#txt").val();
        var url = "http://dir/dir/Default.aspx?";           

        url += "txt=" + escape(txt);

        // Loop through all the selects         
        $("select").each(function () {
            url += "&" + $(this).attr("id") + "=" + escape($(this).val());
        });

        // Change the image source attribute
        $("#img").attr("src", url);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/67WaW/

I would suggest that you generate the image URL just when the user actually finishes the selection, so:

```
// Just a shortcut for the document ready
$(function () {
    // When the user finishes the selection    
    $("select:last").on("change", function () {
        var txt = $("#txt").val();
        var url = "http://dir/dir/Default.aspx?";           

        url += "txt=" + escape(txt);

        // Loop through all the selects         
        $("select").each(function () {
            url += "&" + $(this).attr("id") + "=" + escape($(this).val());
        });

        // Change the image source attribute
        $("#img").attr("src", url);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/67WaW/1/

It's up to you to decide which way to go.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be just what I need, and much more succinctly  written.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready (function(){
DrawImg();
});

function DrawImg() {

    var txt = $("#txt").val();
    var test1 = $("#1").val();// variable name must be valid
    var test2 = $("#2").val();
    var test3 = $("#3").val();


        var url = 'http://dir/dir/Default.aspx?';
        url += 'txt=' + escape(txt);
        url += '&1=' + escape(test1);
        url += '&2=' + escape(test2);
        url += '&3=' + escape(test3);

         $("#pContainer").html("<img src='"+url+"'/>");
    }
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LArBW/31/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery code to this.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
DrawImg();
});
function DrawImg() {
var txt = $("#txt").val();
var t1 = $("#1 option:selected").val;
var t2 = $("#2 option:selected").val;
var t3 = $("#3 option:selected").val;
var url = 'http://dir/dir/Default.aspx?';
url += 'txt=' + escape(txt);
url += '&1=' + escape(1);
url += '&2=' + escape(2);
url += '&3=' + escape(3);
alert('
<img src='+url+'/>
');
$("#pContainer").html('
<img src='+url+'/>
');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code URL is a variable, so concatenate the string with variable using '+' operator.